# If $X,Y\in \mathfrak X^1(S^2)$ commute, then $X$ and $Y$ have a common singularity?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Original title: Dados dos campos de vectores $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}^{r}(M)$ que conmutan

Estoy aprendiendo ecuaciones diferenciales ordinarias y me piden que haga un bosquejo de la demostración de la siguiente proposición:
Si $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}^{1}\left(S^{2}\right)$ conmutan, entonces $X$ e $Y$ tienen una singularidad común. Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

---

Translation to English:

I am learning ordinary differential equations and I am asked to sketch a proof of the following proposition: If $X,Y\in \mathfrak X^1(S^2)$ commute, then $X$ and $Y$ have a common singularity. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Por favor, escriba en ingles.

Comment: Si escribes en español reduces la posibilidad de que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Please check if my translation is ok :)